# setting tab index for nested forms and canvas in smartgwt

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, tabindex, tab-ordering

I have a smart gwt application which includes `VLayouts`, `HLayouts`, `DynamicForms`, `Canvas`, etc in a nested fashion.
One form comes inside of another in many places across the application.
But the **tab order** (Navigation using **Tab** and **Shift+Tab**) is behaving in a random order in many places.
Can anyone provide some suggestions for overall archetecture of the application?

*For example*

- Which method should be used `vLaout.addMember(myPanel)` or
  `vLayout.addChild(myPanel)`?
- How to properly nest the components?
- should globalTabIndex be used ?
- If two forms are added to a VLaoyout, how can I specify the TabIndex to specify which form's components should be focused first ?

I didnt find any proper documentaion in smartgwt website. Please help me. Any kind of suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

- addMember(Widget widget) shall be used - at least in most cases.
- Organize them in logical panels (all components of a form in a form container, all the forms in a layout container and all the layout containers in higher order layout containers)
- Depends on your case. You are not very clear on what you want to achieve with it.
- DynamicForm is a Canvas. Use focus() at the form you want to be shown firstly focused to the user.

The http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc if very useful to find out about the objects supported methods and actions.